# Как вывести 3 изображения из статьи вместо миниатюры?

Tags: wordpress

Вывожу под статьей похожие статьи, хочу вывести в них не 1 миниатюру, а 3 изображения из статьи.
Как вывести 3 изображения из статьи вместо миниатюры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте с использованием плагина ACF. Добавьте поле в таксономию записей "Изображения статьи", например. Туда внесите свои изображения, и в нужном месте выведите через `the_field("....")`.

Что бы получить картинки,прикрепленные к посту можно сделать так:

```
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $id );
print_r( $media );
```

На выходе будем массив с картинками, его уже обработайте, как вам необходимо.

```
            <?php 
                    // Я делал это в single.php, поэтому если делаете в др.шаблонах, то получите ID нужного поста сначала.

                    $media = get_attached_media( 'image', the_ID() );

                    // Раскомментируйте , что бы увидеть весь массив.
                    // print_r( $media ); 

                    //Получим картинки
                    $idx = 0;
                    foreach ($media as $item){
                        if ($idx < 3) echo '<img src="'.$item->guid.'">';
                            $idx++;
                    } 
                
                ?>
```

Comment: "Туда внесите свои изображени"
они не мои а должны из статьи браться

Comment: Обновил ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Был бы вам очень признателен за весь код.

Comment: Сейчас я нашел только код вывода 1 картинки.

Comment: А мне надо 3 вывести

Comment: //ВЫВОД ПЕРВОЙ КАРТИНКИ С ПОСТА
function first_post_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
  if(empty($first_img)){
  }
  return $first_img;
}
вывожу
<?php echo first_post_image() ?>

Comment: Добавил код. Проверил у себя, все работает.

Comment: Какая то цифра впереди изображений встает.

Comment: https://allremont59.ru/instrumentyi-materialyi/kak-pravilno-sushit-doski.html
внизу статьи похожие статьи, там 3 фото норм выводятся но цифры какие то вначале повляются

Comment: Замените the_id на get_the_ID()

Comment: не понадобилось, я просто удалил его $media = get_attached_media( 'image' );
так как ранее же он уже был получен
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

Comment: Сейчас так
          
  <?php 
                    $media = get_attached_media( 'image' );
                    //Получим картинки
                    $idx = 0; 
                    foreach ($media as $item){
                        if ($idx < 3) echo '<img src="'.$item->guid.'">';
                            $idx++;
                    } 
            ?>

Comment: с вами можно связаться?

Comment: В профиле есть мои контакты. Другие я сразу дать не могу.